# Setting up php development environment in netbeans 8.1 on Windows 7

Tags: php, netbeans, vhosts, ampps

I am working in PHP and want to add the source code as existing project in Netbeans 8.1 on Windows 7 using Ampps.

I have setup virtual hosts and edited the hosts file to create the local site www.mysite.com. Here is the code snippet

httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  <Directory "c:/program files/ampps/www/mysite/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
  </Directory>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/program files/ampps/www/mysite/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "c:/program files/ampps/www/mysite/www"
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/Ampps/apache/logs/www.mysite.com.err"
CustomLog "C:/Program Files/Ampps/apache/logs/www.mysite.com.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file

> 127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com

Now as I set up a project in Netbeans with existing sources at the Run Configuration step, the Project URL appears as http:\localhost\www. I want this to be www.mysite.com. How to do this?

Any help appreciated.

[Create project from existing source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNTvr.jpg)

The image shows the project URL as http:\localhost\www.If it is changed then it displays Project URL is not valid as below

[Invalid Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZgNW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Creating New Project**

Add **Project URL** and remove index file text if not required.

[image]

**Already Created Project**

Right click on your **Project** and Select **Properties**. Select **Run Configuration** in the left tab. Edit the Project URL as shown in screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Bilal, I haven't yet created the project.It is while creating projects using existing  sources and in it the last step Run configuration

Comment: Updated the answer for new projects